# Body params disappear on some POST requests routes

Tags: rest, post, parameters, graphql, http-post

I have some rest and GraphQL services works with ruby and typescript (with nestjs framework).
I've noticed that a couple of days ago some of the POST requests failed due to params validation error.
After further investagaion, it seems like on some requests the body params sphoradicly drops from the requests somewhere on the network. It happen for small amount of requests (less than 1%).
This issue started when no changes deployed on the server or clients side. My clients are iOS and android apps and it happens for both platforms.

I've tried to find the exact point on the network that the body dropped, with no success.I've also tried to find a solutions to similar issue on the net.

Does anyone have any idea what can it be? I haven'e found any relevant information about similar issues.

Thanks!